# Unable to add Conference in Calendar API using Python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have my conference details part included in event as

```
'conferenceData': {'createRequest': {'conferenceSolutionKey': {'type': 'eventHangout'}}}
```

and the event creation call looks like

```
service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event, conferenceDataVersion=1).execute()
```

I am unable to find a through python example for adding conference option in Calendar API. I have mapped the above event format using JavaScript example. Thanks!